# XMLRPC Delete Wordpress Post with wp.deletePost

Tags: php, wordpress, xml-rpc

I am trying to delete a wordpress post with XMLRPC, I created a function but it returns a strange thing:

```
function deletePost($rpcurl,$username,$password,$post_id) 
{
// xmlrpc settings
$params = array(0,$username,$password,$post_id);

// run xmlrpc
$request = xmlrpc_encode_request('wp.deletePost', $params);
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $rpcurl);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);  
$results = curl_exec($ch);  
curl_close($ch);

// testing
var_dump( $results);
return $results;  
}
```

Here's what is being returned (once stripped some of the xml tags down):

```
<name>faultCode</name>
<value><int>-32601</int></value>
<name>faultString</name>
<value><string>server error. requested method wp.deletePost does not exist.</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

It actually is what it says it is...there is no such method on xmlrpc server, because wp doesn't allow to delete posts by itself... But in the xmlrpc there is a method for blogger api called **blogger.deletePost**. It should do what you want. As I look at your code, I think you only need to fix two things, change your third line of code into

```
$request = xmlrpc_encode_request('blogger.deletePost', $params);
```

and also, your **$params** should be an array, with values on [1] being post_id, [2] username a [3] password.

**EDIT**: It obviously exists from version 3.4., so you could either use the solution above, or use the *wp.deletePost* with **$params** with values on [1] username a [2] password and [3] post_id.

Comment: thanks a lot, it works perfectly, if that method doesn't exist, why is it documented here http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Posts#wp.deletePost

Comment: And that's for the "yet" part :D It obviously does now...I looked into an old xmlrpc file which doesn't have this feature yet...sorry for misleading info, but in that case, I'm not sure why your code didn't work in the first place...Are you sure you have your upragraded to the latest version (since this has been added in 3.4)?